# Angular 5 http call not firing

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http

Http calls are not firing. I wrote the call on subscribe of route params. The call gets fires on full page reload or first time I click the button to change the route. After that the call doesn't fire. I checked network sec of chrome dev tools. No calls there.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getSlider();
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(qParams => {
            this.boxSlug = params.slug;
            if (qParams.box_standard) {
                if (qParams.box_standard === "previous") {

                    console.log('blah blah blah');

                    this.pageType = qParams.box_standard;
                    this.getPreviousBoxes(); //<---method that gets called
                } else if (qParams.box_standard === "box-detail") {
                    this.pageType = "box-detail";
                    this.boxFBIN = qParams.box;
                    this.getBoxDetail(qParams.box);
                } else {
                    this.pageType = "box";
                    if (params.slug && this.pageType === "box") {
                        this.boxSlug = params.slug;
                        this.getBoxTypes(params.slug);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                this.pageType = "box";
                if (params.slug) {
                    this.getBoxTypes(params.slug);
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(["/box"]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

getPreviousBoxes() {
    this.boxService.getPreviousBoxes(this.boxSlug).subscribe(
        response => {

            console.log('preResp--->', response);

            this.previousBoxes = [];
            this.boxChunk = [];
            this.previousBoxes = response.data;
            while (this.previousBoxes.length > 0) {
                this.boxChunk.push(this.previousBoxes.splice(0, 4));
            }
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error.error.message);
        }
    );
}
```

This is http call in my BoxService.service.ts (not full code)

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export class BoxService {

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
private API_URL = environment.API_URL;
private headerDict = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
};
private requestOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders(this.headerDict)
};


getPreviousBoxes(boxSlug): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this.API_URL + 'user/box/previous/' + boxSlug, this.requestOptions)
    .map(response => {

        console.log('bbbbbb====>', response);
        console.log('boxSlug====>', boxSlug);

        return response;
    }).catch(this.handleError);
}
}
```

dev tools network and console on page reload:

[the api call and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m7eX.png)

[log of the response but array length is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWbCO.png)

if i initiate the call without reload the following happens (after clearing console and network tabs):

[no api call registers in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GUc4.png)

[but somehow i get a response and it gets logged in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvIqm.png)

Can anyone help me understand hat the issue is?

Comment: you have API call on `ngOninit()`?

Comment: @Abhishek ya. I subscribe to the queryParams on it. Is there any issue?

Comment: refer this link, this will helps you https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: Please avoid referencing images. Reference code instead, it's hard to keep track of what's happening. That said, in your callback, do `return response.data` instead.

Comment: Please feel free to paste the related code instead images!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method. Just return the service call result without using map operator. Hope, you are using HttpClientModule

```
getPreviousBoxes(boxSlug) {
    return this._http.get(this.API_URL + 'users/box/previous' + boxSlug,this.requestOptions);
  }
```

Comment: this didin't work. got same response and situations. I just can't figure of why there no call being fired but gets a response.

Comment: No there is none